# Identify plant with blue berries and jagged leaves

Tags: identification, berries

This is from Northwest United States.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oregon grape (*Mahonia aquifolium*). It is native to western North America, but also commonly used as decorative plant in other parts of the world.

The grapes are very sour, so please find more information online first if you want to try them. Please read how to eat them and when, how to prepare them.

Comment: I agree ,however , I have bought that plant in IL and it was named "Osmanthus" which looks similar.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be either Oregon grape or Cascade Barberry (toxic), you be the judge.